# Android Self-signed certificate cannot be verified without a previous internet connection

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, self-signed

**Working SSL infrastructure:**

We have a working client/server setup where phones with the Android versions 4.2 and 4.4 act as clients that have to verify a server by its self-signed SSL certificate.

**The problem:**

The server certificate verification works as long as the devices have had internet access at least once before attempting to connect. However, if a factory reset is performed and the devices directly connect to a private network without internet connection the certificate verification fails.

To reproduce the behavior:

1. Factory reset the phone
2. Restart without choosing to connect to a WiFi with internet access
3. Try to verify a self-signed SSL certificate -> **FAILS**
4. Connect to a WiFi with internet access
5. Reconnect to the original private network
6. Try to verify a self-signed SSL certificate -> **WORKS**

Technically, the devices should not need internet access to verify the self signed certificate. Could there be some kind of a blacklist that has to be loaded once before any SSL server verification can take place? And can I prevent this behavior?

**Creating the SSL context:**

```
    //Using a client certificate
    String password = "clientpass";
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
    keyStore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
    is.close();
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    kmf.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();


    // Using self signed certificate
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cacert);
    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Certificate ca;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        Log.i("CA","ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null);
    trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    tmf.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our Trustmanager and Keymanager
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    sslcontext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

    //create a socket to connect with the server
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(serverAddr, port);
    socket.setUseClientMode(true);
    socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(this);
    socket.startHandshake();
```

**Fails with the exception in startHandshake:**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not     validate certificate: null
```

Comment: What are you using for the HTTP requests? `WebView`? `HttpUrlConnection`? `OkHttp`? `HttpClient`? Something else?

Comment: I am building my own SSLContext to create SSLSockets with a specific Truststore and Keystore.

Comment: If you skip steps #2 and #3, does it work on the first try? IOW, are you sure that this isn't a first-use failure, instead of a no-Internet-access failure? What are your specific test devices? Are you able to reproduce this problem on one of the SDK's emulators (when running on a development machine connected solely to the private network)?

Comment: If I had internet access once before connecting to my private server it works without any problem

Comment: Show code and stack trace/logcat.

Comment: Your code looks OK, but is there a reason to call `startHandshake()` explicitly? Do you have the full stack trace? Anything interesting in logcat before/after/during the connection? Does it work when not using client authentication?

Comment: Stupid question, but is the time on your device right? Looking at `RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java`, this message is only produced for expired/not yet valid certs. If you don't have Internet, the device can't sync time with NTP, so it is very likely that the date is set to year 2000 or something like this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make sure the time on the device is correct, certificates have a validity period and won't validate if the date is set to the past (usually Jan 1st, 2000 after a factory reset) or future. The device will automatically sync via NTP, but that obviously doesn't work when there is no usable Internet connection.

Comment: Good find. Damn, I've been bitten by that so many times in the past I can't count... Usually it was over the cellular radios, though (no Wifi/BT). I'm surprised it did not jump out at me.